# Hadoop job error in dataproc gui version on Google cloud

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to create a job for wordcount using **org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount** but it shows errors:

I am attaching images of my job configuration and also where are the files located in my bucket(I am using buckets and not hdfs)

Job configuration used:

[image: These are my job configuartion]

Files are stored in bucket:
[image: the 2nd file in screenshot is hadoop-mapreduce-examples.ar]

URI for hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar:[image]

The error i got when I used above configurations:
[image: Job failed with message [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]. Additional details can be found at: https://console.cloud.google.com/dataproc/jobs/job-58ef7440?project=hadoop-304309&region=us-central1 gcloud dataproc jobs wait 'job-58ef7440' --region 'us-central1' --project 'hadoop-304309' https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/wordbucket01/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/7e251bd2-bd3f-4915-aea3-fba5789e6ee3/jobs/job-58ef7440/ gs://wordbucket01/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/7e251bd2-bd3f-4915-aea3-fba5789e6ee3/jobs/job-58ef7440/driveroutput]

The job output:
[image: The job output,"5 more " written at last is not clickable and I can't even expand that so its not possible what's there in those 5 more lines]
The driver outputfile:
[image: DriverOutputFile]

Comment: Can you please paste the content of the driveroutput file ? It is located in the last location in the error message

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz I have included now, please check. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by default Hadoop won't write to an existing path, unless an "overwrite" mode has been specifically asked for. You have two options:

- Delete the output path before running the example
- Use another output path for each run

In general, the output of the job can be found in the Google Cloud console - look for the "Jobs" page under Dataproc, or for the Jobs tab under the cluster page. Also, as presented here, the output is saved to GCS and you can always retrieve it from there.

Comment: Is there any way I can include some script to change the path accordingly.. for example I would do something like "output/ex1" for first run "output/ex2" for second run and so on...Is there any way to somethig like this, if yes ,please include a reference link , as I am new to hadoop and learning things gradually.Thanks